# Retrieving jsonp data from external domain using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Im using an example code I got on internet, the jquery part is:

```
$.ajax({
     url: punctis_content_url + "?url=" + encodeURIComponent(document.URL),
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success:function(json){
         alert(json);
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     }
     });
```

And the php on the remote server is:

```
    $arr = array('URL' => $trackUrl, 'param2' => "element2");
    echo($_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($arr).");");
```

This is working fine, I got the alert from the jquery and if I call directly the server script i got: `jsonp1357658534513({"URL":"http:\/\/infoabout.me\/punctis\/punctis.php","param2":"element2"});`

The thing is, how the callback code is generated?, what it means? and how i can retrieve the data (URL, and param2) from that json because using just json.URL does not work. Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn how JSONP works. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json` in this case is a javascript object. Simply pull the data from it's properties.

```
alert(json.URL) // $trackUrl value
alert(json.param2) // element2
```

Answer (score 0):

jsonp is created by wrapping the json string generated by a javascript function invocation, a PHP example for this would be:

```
$callbackFunction = $_GET['callback'];
echo $callbackFunction . "(" . json_encode($object) . ")";
```

now, once the jsonp is retrieved the function is invoked, this function could be wired automagically using the likes of jQuery, dojo or other js frameworks, or hardcoded, you could, for example write the following function, and it'll be invoked in your specific case. good luck!

```
function jsonp1357658534513(string){
    console.log(string);
}
```